# capture 2 texts from the screen and compare them using AutoHotkey

Tags: compare, screen, capture, autohotkey

I'm working with AutoHotkey and I need to capture two sentences from my screen and compare them. Anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What have you done so far and where specifically in your code are you struggling? Share your code by editing the original question, paste the code, highlight the code and press [Ctrl]+k to format that portion as a code block.

Comment: Hi, 
I'm just starting with the code. The problem won't be to compare the sentences, but to capture them into variables.
I just need to know how to capture some text from my screen, that's all, but I can't find how to do it. 
I guess it shoul be something like this:

**MouseClickDrag,left, 540,  295, 602,  295**

**ControlGetText, VAR, 602,  295**

But it doesn't work, because the comand:

**Send, %VAR%**

sends nothing, so I haven't captured the text into VAR.

I hope you can help me, I'm sure it has to be very easy.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this shows some effort.

When you use mouseClickDrag, you have to be absolutely sure that the text will ALWAYS be at those exact locations, which is very unlikely, think about a menu bar moving the webpage down, or about using F11, doing the opposite, changing the font style/size, just zooming in/out, or making the window smaller, such that the text block becomes smaller in width but longer in length, having another banner add that is smaller or larger, et cetera. If you can use an other method (e.g. Find text and from that position, jump 10 words to the left (^{Left 10}) and then select the next 5 words (+^{Right 5}), would be much more reliable.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
Return ; Stop here on startup to prevent running the whole script on startup

+Insert::  ; Using the [Shift]+[Insert] Key as the hotkey here.
MouseClickDrag,left, 540, 295, 602, 295 ; HighLight area1
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 2
MyVar1:=ClipBoard ; OR MyVar1 = %ClipBoard%

MouseClickDrag,left, 540, 295, 602, 295 ; HighLight area2
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 2
MyVar2:=ClipBoard ; OR MyVar2 = %ClipBoard%

If (MyVar1 = MyVar2)
{
    MsgBox, The values %MyVar1% and %MyVar2% are equal
    Send, %MyVar1%
    ; ClipBoard:=MyVar1 ; OR ClipBoard = %MyVar1%  is alternative way (Faster)
    ; Send, ^v
}
Else
{
    MsgBox, The values %MyVar1% and %MyVar2% are NOT equal
    Send, %MyVar1% AND %MyVar2%
    ; ClipBoard = %MyVar1% AND %MyVar2% ; is alternative way (Faster)
    ; Send, ^v
}
Return
```

You could add some tests to only execute this when Chrome, FireFox or IE is active, but I have left that out. First chew on this code.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm working with a static screen where everything is always in the same place, but thank you for the warning anyway.
I've already tried your code and it works perfectly. Again thank you very much for your help, I'm very grateful.

Comment: Since you are new to this community. There is a white check mark next to the answer(s). If you feel one particular answer was most useful, you can click on that check mark to turn it green and show that the question was answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: All right. I've already done it. If there is any other way to give you votes explain it to me and I'd be pleased to give you my vote or whatever.
Thanks again!